# In Elasticsearch, what is the difference between es.discovery.nodes=false and es.nodes.wan.only=true?

Tags: elasticsearch

While reading about the different configuration options in https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/5.6/configuration.html
I came around the options `es.discovery.nodes` and `es.nodes.wan.only`. While they seem to be doing somethings similar, disabling the discovery of new nodes not included in `es.nodes`, `es.nodes.wan.only` is said to highly impact the systems performance.

Is `es.discovery.nodes` also impacting the performance negatively, when `es.nodes` has all the elastic nodes defined?

What are the differences between one parameter and the other?

Thanks,